# Ansible best practice to copy directories

Tags: ansible

In my playbook I have

```
- name: Grab h5bp/server-configs-nginx
  git:  repo=https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx.git
        dest=/tmp/server-configs-nginx
        version="3db5d61f81d7229d12b89e0355629249a49ee4ac"
        force=yes

- name: Copy over h5bp configuration
  command: cp -r /tmp/server-configs-nginx/{{ item }} /etc/nginx/{{ item }}
  with_items:
    - "mime.types"
    - "h5bp/"
```

Which raises the warning in ansible-lint:

```
[ANSIBLE0006] cp used in place of copy module
/Users/austinpray/Dropbox/DEV/opensauce/bedrock-ansible/roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml:0
Task/Handler: Copy over h5bp configuration
```

So this raises the question: is there a better way to do this with ansible modules rather than a command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, `command` is your best option. There's no remote-to-remote option. Here's a thread about it: [How to move/rename a file using an Ansible task on a remote system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162996/how-to-move-rename-a-file-using-an-ansible-task-on-a-remote-system)

You have a couple other options:

- you could use the `file` module to make a symlink (by setting `src`, `path`, and `state=link`.
- you could check out the repo on the Ansible server and then use `copy`. This is a more common model for deploying code.
- you can keep using `command` but wrap it with a `stat` conditional so it only overwrites once. This is especially helpful if you use `notify` to restart nginx.

Finally, it looks like you might be doing a "deploy by git". That isn't always the best choice, *especially* if you don't "own" that repo. But it could be fine- just a bit of code smell.

Comment: "Finally, it looks like you might be doing a 'deploy by git'."

Here is the context. This is only a small portion of setting up the server. I basically am just grabbing some useful server configs from a remote repo maintained by the community.
https://github.com/roots/bedrock-ansible/issues/31

Comment: ended up just ditching ansible-lint haha

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`synchronize` module](http://docs.ansible.com/synchronize_module.html) with `mode='pull'`

```
- name: Copy over h5bp configuration
 synchronize: mode=pull src=/tmp/server-configs-nginx/{{ item }} dest=/etc/nginx/{{ item }} 
 with_items:
   - "mime.types"
   - "h5bp/"
```

**Note**: To copy remote-to-remote, use the same command and add `delegate_to` (as remote source) and current `inventory_host` (as remote dest)

Comment: In ansible 2.2, using sychronize module as described in this answer or using command module with 'cp' as described in the question are the only ways of copying directories from remote to remote.

Comment: This sounds promising but I can't make sense of your "note:". Can you post a full example for doing deep remote-to-remote file copies?

I'm trying to copy a web-root directory from an NFS share onto the local disk of each web server in a pool. Say from /nfs/www to /var/www.

Answer (score 7):

Ansible 2.0 brings the `remote_src` parameter to the `copy` module: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html

Now you just need to do something like:

```
- name: Copy over h5bp configuration
  copy: src=/tmp/server-configs-nginx/{{ item }} dest=/etc/nginx/{{ item }} remote_src=yes
  with_items:
    - "mime.types"
    - "h5bp"
```

Comment: Remote copy (copy module with remote_src parameter set to 'true') does not support recursive copy of directory and the question is about copying directories, so this answer is useless

Comment: @AlanEvangelista hmm you're right, bah that sucks. I think the answer is still useful though as it's still possible to list all files.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to zip your folder before and use the `unarchive ansible` module:

```
- name: copy your folder using a work around
  unarchive: src=your.zip dest=/destinationfolder
  become: yes
```

This will unzip your folder on your destination so you have a folder copy ;-)
but don't forget to have **unzip** package on your target machine.

RHEL   :

> yum install unzip -y

Debian :

> apt install unzip

Answer (score 1):

- copy: src={{ item }} dest=/etc/fooapp/ directory_mode=yes

user directory_mode field.

Comment: please provide more of an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You could use with_fileglob: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#id4

```
# copy each file over that matches the given pattern
- copy: src={{ item }} dest=/etc/fooapp/ owner=root mode=600
  with_fileglob:
    - /playbooks/files/fooapp/*
```

Comment: with_fileglob only searches local files, the question is about copying files from remote to remote, so this answer is useless

Comment: This answer is indeed incorrect for this context. But for me this was exactly what I needed. Thanks for posting :)!

Comment: Mmmh, fileglob is non-recursive.