# Move files on remote system, only if destination doesn't exist, with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write an Ansible role that moves a number of files on the remote system. I found a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24165405/1174185) about how to do this, which essentially says "just use the command module with 'mv'". I have a single task defined with a `with_items` statement like this where each item in `dirs` is a dictionary with `src` and `dest` keys:

```
- name: Move directories
  command: mv {{ item.src }} {{ item.dest }}
  with_items: dirs
```

This is good and it works, but I run into problems if the destination directory already exists. I don't want to overwrite it, so I thought about trying to stat each `dest` directory first. I wanted to update the `dirs` variable with the stat info, but as far as I know, there isn't a good way to set or update variables once they're defined. So I used `stat` to get the info on each directory and then saved the data with `register`:

```
- name: Check if directories already exist
  stat: path={{ item.dest }}
  with_items: dirs
  register: dirs_stat
```

Is there a way to tie the registered stat info to the `mv` commands? This would be easy if it were a single directory. The looping is what makes this tricky. Is there a way to do this without unrolling this loop into two tasks per directory?

Comment: since you are already using shell, you can do something like `if not -d {{item}} mv {{item}} {{dest}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the simplest solution by any means, but if you wanted to use Ansible and not "unroll":

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    dirs:
      - src: /home/ubuntu/src/test/src1
        dest: /home/ubuntu/src/test/dest1
      - src: /home/ubuntu/src/test/src2
        dest: /home/ubuntu/src/test/dest2
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: "{{item.dest}}"
      with_items: dirs
      register: dirs_stat
    - debug:
        msg: "should not copy {{ item.0.src }}"
      with_together:
        - dirs
        - dirs_stat.results
      when: item.1.stat.exists
```

Simply adapt the debug task to run the appropriate `command` task instead and `when:` to `when: not ...`.

Comment: Oh! `with_together` seems like it might work. It's in the docs, but I guess I missed it.

Comment: @erynofwales, great. Let me know if there's any delta with the answer being acceptable :]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **stat** keyword in your **playbook** to check if it exists or not if it doesn't then move.

```
---
- name: Demo Playbook
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: check destination
    stat:
     path: /path/to/dest
    register: p
  - name:  copy file if not exists
    command: mv /path/to/src /path/to/src
    when: p.stat.exists == False
```