# Use Shell Command "mv" using ansible to move folder from one to another

Tags: ansible

I want to move my workspace3 folder to /usr/share directory using below Ansible scripts. But I am unable to move it.

```
 - name: Move workspace3 directory to /usr/share/ Folder
   command: mv /tmp/workspace3/ /usr/share
```

I also tried with shell module

```
   shell: mv /tmp/workspace3 /usr/share
```

I believe it is a permission issue, how can I define permission through ansible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/usr/share is a directory owned by the root user. In order to create folders (or move folders) into this directory, you must use priviledged escalation. This is very simple with ansible, simply use the following in your playbook;

```
become: yes
```

Make sure that when you run your playbook you use the -K flag which will ask you for the sudo password, assuming you do not have NOPASSWD configured for that user in your sudoers file. The default user that "become" uses is root.

Doc: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html

Comment: "Make sure that when you run your playbook you use the -K flag which will ask you for the sudo password." -- Assuming that you don't have passwordless sudo enabled for that user.

Comment: Fair enough. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

In version 2.0 use copy module with *remote_src* parameter.

```
- name: Move workspace3 directory to /usr/share/ Folder
  become: yes
  copy:
    remote_src: yes
    src: /tmp/workspace3
    dest: /usr/share/
```

If you want to move file you need to delete old file with file module

```
- name: Remove old files foo
  file:
    path: /tmp/workspace3
    state: absent
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: Note that if you try to copy folder that has files in it it will not work (ansible 2.2.2.0), you need to use alternative from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162996/how-to-move-rename-a-file-using-an-ansible-task-on-a-remote-system#comment47150350_24457830