# Ansible moving files

Tags: automation, ansible, devops

I am creating a role to deploy Jira instance. My question is, how I can move files from one directory to another, I was trying something like this:

```yaml
- name: Create Jira installation directory
  command: mv "/tmp/atlassian-jira-software-{{ jira_version }}-standalone/*" "{{ installation_directory }}"
  when: not is_jira_installed.stat.exists
```

But It's not working, I want to copy all files from one directory to another without copying the directory.

Comment: Is it throwing an error message?  What is the value of `jira_version`?  Of `installation_directory`?  Try removing the quotation marks.

Comment: just for clarification, you are not moving files from control node (where your ansible is running) to a remote host?

Comment: question does not specify if this move is done on remote or controller node, also what is the issue with the task provided ? was any error observed ? was it not accomplishing the desired behavior ?

Comment: I want to move files from one dest to another on the remote host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the synopsis of the `command` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#synopsis):

> The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like `$HOSTNAME` and operations like `"*"`, `"<"`, `">"`, `"|"`, `";"` and `"&"` will not work. Use the [ansible.builtin.shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-shell-module) module if you need these features.

So, your issue is the fact that the `command` module is not expanding the wildcard `*`, as you expect it, you should be using the `shell` module instead:

```yaml
- name: Create Jira installation directory
  shell: "mv /tmp/atlassian-jira-software-{{ jira_version }}-standalone/* {{ installation_directory }}"
  when: not is_jira_installed.stat.exists
```

---

Now, please note that you can also make this without having to resort to a `command` or `shell`, by using the [`copy` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html).

```yaml
- copy:
    src: "/tmp/atlassian-jira-software-{{ jira_version }}-standalone/"
    dest: "{{ installation_directory }}"
    remote_src: yes
```

Comment: But this copy module will copy the whole directory not only files in it.

Comment: Not if you end the directory with a slash, as explained in the docs: _If path is a directory, it is copied recursively. In this case, if path ends with "/", only inside contents of that directory are copied to destination. Otherwise, if it does not end with "/", the directory itself with all contents is copied._ https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-src

Comment: I don't suppose it's possible to *move* the files with the copy module, right? For instance, when using this, the files in the original destination are still present, rather than being removed.

Comment: @dem indeed, this has been answered here, by the way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162996/how-to-move-rename-a-file-using-an-ansible-task-on-a-remote-system